# SQL Server Service Broker or Async Window Service?

Tags: c#

I have a stage table which is like a queue, data keeps coming to this table.

Can I write a window service runs continuously and read data from queue table and apply some business logic on the records, for this approach could you please share some code link, etc?

Or should I consider SQL Server Service Broker?

Please suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a table as a queue, then use a table as a queue. I recommend you read [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/).

I do not recommend using Service Broker unless you need [activation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617(v=sql.105).aspx). Service Broker is designed for distributed applications and comes with significant overhead when compared with a simple queue table (conversations, services and contracts etc).

Comment: could u please suggest some sample code console/window app that connects tables as Queues.

Comment: the article linked has all the T-SQL code you need. Using SQL from C# is straightforward.